# Airflow S3KeySensor Timeout to Another Operator

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a usecase where if the S3KeySensor times out then I want to trigger a different Airflow Step Operator and continue my DAG run. Currently it raises an error AirflowSensorTimeout('Snap. Time is OUT.'). Is there any way to implement this?

```
scan_results_sensor = S3KeySensor(
        task_id="key_sensor",
        bucket_key=key,
        wildcard_match=True,
        bucket_name=bucket,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        timeout=120,
        poke_interval=30,
        soft_fail=True
    )
```

Comment: specifically only on Timeout? Where is the other operator (same dag? other?) Please add more details about the use case. Add samples of your current code

Comment: Yes timeout only. It should trigger another operator from within the dag.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is setting `trigger_rule="all_failed"` or `trigger_rule="one_failed"` (based on your operator dependencies). However, you are providing `soft_fail=True`, it sets the operator state to `skipped` on failure. So, it should be also removed.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules